# PXSelect based on a custom checkbox field

Tags: customization, acumatica

I have added a custom checkbox field (UsrRegionManager) to the Employee screen so that the customer can designate a limited number of employees as regional managers.  I am trying to add a custom field (UsrDefServiceManager) to the Project screen to identify the default service manager responsible for the project.  I want to limit the selection of employees to only region managers.

```
 public class ContractExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CT.Contract>
 {
   public class cbTrue: Constant<int>
   {
     public cbTrue()
     : base(1)
     {
     }
   }

   #region UsrDefServiceManager
   [PXDBInt]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName="Def Region Manager")]
   [PXSelector(typeof(Search<EPEmployee.bAccountID,
            Where<EPEmployee.usrRegionManager, Equal<cbTrue>>>),
            typeof(EPEmployee.acctCD),
            typeof(EPEmployee.acctName),
            typeof(EPEmployee.vStatus),
            typeof(EPEmployee.departmentID),
            SubstituteKey = typeof(EPEmployee.acctCD),
            DescriptionField = typeof(EPEmployee.acctName))]
   public virtual int? UsrDefServiceManager { get; set; }
   public abstract class usrDefServiceManager : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrDefServiceManager> { }
   #endregion
 }
```

In this variation I receive an error that usrRegionManager does not exist in EPEmployee.  I've tried defining EPEmployeeExt as an extension of EPEmployee and tried using PX.Objects.EP.Extensions.  But no luck so far.

Comment: Please post your definition for usrRegionManager.  If I had to guess, you should change the 'u' to a 'U'

Comment: The usrRegionManager field was part of a separate customization package called "Emmployees" that customized the Employee screen EP203000.  When I look at the element properties the data class is EPEmployee and the field is UsrRegionManager.

Comment: In the customization package under Data Access the extension is CR.BAccount.  The BQL Field is BAccountExt.usrRegionManager of the PXDBBool type.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a field in a DAC extension right alongside the base DAC fields, just replace YourEPEmployeeExtension with the class name of your dac extension

```
 ... typeof(Search<EPEmployee.bAccountID,
        Where<YourEPEmployeeExtension.usrRegionManager, Equal<cbTrue>>>), ...
```

Comment: Based on your comment, I changed the code to:       [PXSelector(typeof(Search<EPEmployee.bAccountID,
                Where<BAccountExt.usrRegionManager, Equal<cbTrue>>>),
and it publishes but it does not restrict the selection.  I tried changing the cbTrue constant to bool with a value of true but that didn't work either.  I also tried adding:                 typeof(BAccountExt.usrRegionManager),
to the list of fields in the selection window but it doesn't show up.

Comment: , Equal<True>  PX.Data.True

Comment: Can I see the definition of usrRegionManager DAC Field?

Answer (score 0):

If the field is in another customization, you have add that customization's dll as a reference in your current project. Then you would be able to reference the usrRegionManager field in that customization. For example, if the other customization is called Emmployees, then the reference would be something like this:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<EPEmployee.bAccountID,
        Where<Emmployees.EPEmployeeExt.usrRegionManager, Equal<cbTrue>>>),
```